# Setting MaskedTextProvider's AllowPromptAsInput to false does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mask

When I make my [`MaskedTextProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),I set the `AllowPromptAsInput` to false.

```
mtp = new MaskedTextProvider(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, '_', '*', false);
```

In the `OnPreviewTextInput` method of my `TextBox`, I have:

```
    if (e.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        CharacterIsOk = mtp.VerifyChar(e.Text[0], CaretIndex, out dummyHint);
    }
```

`CharacterIsOK` still gets set to true, even when `e.Text[0]` is `_`, which is the default prompt character (I also did `mtp.PromptChar = '_';` just to make sure). The hint tells me that the character was escaped, and reading the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.maskedtextresulthint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.maskedtextprovider.verifyescapechar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I don't see it fulfilling the conditions for an escaped character, since `AllowPromptAsInput` is set to false. I can work around this by checking beforehand if `VerifyEscapeChar` returns true, and if it does, then don't do anything, but why isn't this working like it seems like it should be?